Change product url structure in nopCommerce 4.7.5
i want to change product url structure in nopCommerce 4.7.05. and i change in nopCommerce 4.5 it working fine. but in 4.7.5 it also change url of category. after clicking on category it also add product in url that i don't want.
I want like this on product detail page url
{host}/product/{productname}
and category page want like this url
{host}/{productname}
public void RegisterRoutes(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpointRouteBuilder)
{
var lang = GetLanguageRoutePattern();
 //default routes
 //these routes are not generic, they are just default to map requests that don't match other patterns, 
 //but we define them here since this route provider is with the lowest priority, to allow to add additional routes before them
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lang))
 {
     endpointRouteBuilder.MapControllerRoute(name: "DefaultWithLanguageCode",
         pattern: $"{lang}/{{controller=Home}}/{{action=Index}}/{{id?}}");
 }

 endpointRouteBuilder.MapControllerRoute(name: "Default",
     pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

 if (!DataSettingsManager.IsDatabaseInstalled())
     return;

 //generic routes (actually routing is processed later in SlugRouteTransformer)
 var genericCatalogPattern = $"{lang}/product/{{{NopRoutingDefaults.RouteValue.CatalogSeName}}}/{{{NopRoutingDefaults.RouteValue.SeName}}}";
 endpointRouteBuilder.MapDynamicControllerRoute<SlugRouteTransformer>(genericCatalogPattern);

 var genericPattern = $"{lang}/product/{{{NopRoutingDefaults.RouteValue.SeName}}}";
 endpointRouteBuilder.MapDynamicControllerRoute<SlugRouteTransformer>(genericPattern);

 //routes for not found slugs
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lang))
 {
     endpointRouteBuilder.MapControllerRoute(name: NopRoutingDefaults.RouteName.Generic.GenericUrlWithLanguageCode,
         pattern: genericPattern,
         defaults: new { controller = "Common", action = "GenericUrl" });

     endpointRouteBuilder.MapControllerRoute(name: NopRoutingDefaults.RouteName.Generic.GenericCatalogUrlWithLanguageCode,
         pattern: genericCatalogPattern,
         defaults: new { controller = "Common", action = "GenericUrl" });
 }

 endpointRouteBuilder.MapControllerRoute(name: NopRoutingDefaults.RouteName.Generic.GenericUrl,
     pattern: $"{{{NopRoutingDefaults.RouteValue.SeName}}}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Common", action = "GenericUrl" });

 endpointRouteBuilder.MapControllerRoute(name: NopRoutingDefaults.RouteName.Generic.GenericCatalogUrl,
     pattern: $"{{{NopRoutingDefaults.RouteValue.CatalogSeName}}}/{{{NopRoutingDefaults.RouteValue.SeName}}}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Common", action = "GenericUrl" });

 //routes for entities that support catalog path and slug (e.g. '/category-seo-name/product-seo-name')
 endpointRouteBuilder.MapControllerRoute(name: NopRoutingDefaults.RouteName.Generic.ProductCatalog,
     pattern: genericCatalogPattern,
     defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "ProductDetails" });

 //routes for entities that support single slug (e.g. '/product-seo-name')
 endpointRouteBuilder.MapControllerRoute(name: NopRoutingDefaults.RouteName.Generic.Product,
     pattern: genericPattern,
     defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "ProductDetails" });

 endpointRouteBuilder.MapControllerRoute(name: NopRoutingDefaults.RouteName.Generic.Category,
     pattern: genericPattern,
     defaults: new { controller = "Catalog", action = "Category" });

 endpointRouteBuilder.MapControllerRoute(name: NopRoutingDefaults.RouteName.Generic.Manufacturer,
     pattern: genericPattern,
     defaults: new { controller = "Catalog", action = "Manufacturer" });

 endpointRouteBuilder.MapControllerRoute(name: NopRoutingDefaults.RouteName.Generic.Vendor,
     pattern: genericPattern,
     defaults: new { controller = "Catalog", action = "Vendor" });

 endpointRouteBuilder.MapControllerRoute(name: NopRoutingDefaults.RouteName.Generic.NewsItem,
     pattern: genericPattern,
     defaults: new { controller = "News", action = "NewsItem" });

 endpointRouteBuilder.MapControllerRoute(name: NopRoutingDefaults.RouteName.Generic.BlogPost,
     pattern: genericPattern,
     defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "BlogPost" });

 endpointRouteBuilder.MapControllerRoute(name: NopRoutingDefaults.RouteName.Generic.Topic,
     pattern: genericPattern,
     defaults: new { controller = "Topic", action = "TopicDetails" });

 endpointRouteBuilder.MapControllerRoute(name: NopRoutingDefaults.RouteName.Generic.ProductTag,
     pattern: genericPattern,
     defaults: new { controller = "Catalog", action = "ProductsByTag" });

}
i try to change in this method but it reflect on both product detail and catagory both url.
i only want chnages in productdetail page. please give me solution as soon as possible.
please remember i want solution in nopcomecre 4.7.5
